Lesser known Sefardi commentaries on the Parasha (online)
Very simple question. I am always looking to add to my list of Sefardi (incl. Edot Mizrach, Italian etc.) commentaries that I can draw Divrei Torah from. I have been relying mainly on the Chida, because he has many works, and I resonate with him very well. Also, as a bonus, most of his works are on Sefaria, in full, which saves me money!
I have also been using Rabbi Yosef Chaim's sefarim (also on sefaria) to draw from, as well as R' Avraham Azulai's. There's also, in no particular order, of course Ramban, Ibn Ezra, Or HaChaim Hakodesh, Rabbeinu Bachaye, Sa'adia Ga'on, Maskil LeDavid, Tzror UMor, Sforno and the Alshich Hakodesh.
There are a great many other sefardi gedolim throughout the ages, but I am having trouble sourcing their sefarim online. I am also interested in hearing of lesser known ones, whether online or not, so to boil down my question:
Please recommend Sefardi Rabbonim's commentaries on the Parasha, especially those that are found online, especially rarer ones (and please use my list above to know what not to mention as I already have access to those)

Not "lesser known", but you forgot Ibn Ezra

@Heshy I'm sure there are a few like that

Not sure I'd describe R Saadia Gaon or Seforno as sefardim...

Is the Mizrachi Sefardi?

@CuriousYid Romaniote (Byzantine)

Ben Ish Hai has drashot on the parsha in sefer Ben Ish Hai that's in sefarias halacha section. Sefaria is also going to soon get od yosef hai but they'll be separating the halachot and drashot. It's already up on dictas library (with all the original typos, sefaria is fixing that up)

@Mordechai yes, and a less known sefer called Aderet Eliyahu. I mentioned R Chaim Z'tl in the question

+1 always good to expand the library! Hope you generate some good answers :)

@RabbiKaii i was mentioning the hidden one that doesnt show up on the commentaries.  if theres a particular sefer you want, you can request from sefaria. something i personally do is get a pdf and get dicta to upload it. I learn thru it while correcting errors on dicta's site. this way when im done it available to everyone

Let me introduce you to the fantastic alhatorah.org and in particular their Mikraot Gedolot.
In addition to those you listed above, sefardic Torah commentaries available there include:

R. Yehuda ibn Bil'am
Radak (born in Provence to a family of Spanish origin)
R. Avraham ben HaRambam (born in Egypt to a family of Spanish origin)
Akeidat Yitzchak
Abravanel

Also, depending on how you classify who is a "sefardi", also:

R. Yosef ibn Kaspi (born in Provence but spent much time living in Spain)
Tur (long and short commentaries) (born in Germany but moved to Spain)


Zera Shimshon just released by Artscroll by Rabbi Shimshon Chaim Nachmani from Italy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zera_Shimshon

Do they have anything from the Abuchatzera family? I am having trouble locating anything. No specific sfarim in mind though, so any suggestions or recommendations would be great

+1 for Rabbenu Abhraham and ibn-Kaspi.... if anyone knows where a hard copy of ibn-Kaspi (מצרף לכסף) can be found (preferably a modern print if such exists) I'd be grateful
